# NSMenuItem actions overriding NSPopUpButton actions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

I've noticed an interesting behavior and I wonder if it's something I'm doing wrong.  I have an NSPopUpButton with several NSMenuItems on an NSMenu on the NSPopUpButton. When I click the popup button and select an item the action that I've linked to the NSPopUpButton gets triggered UNLESS the menu item I select defines it's own action:@selector(method).  In that case, the method in the selector gets fired and the other action does not.  I would think both should happen.

Also related to this, if I have selectors on menu items, and I call [popUpButton selectItemAtIndex:index] shouldn't that call the selector on the appropriate menu item?

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: I'm concluding it is in fact the correct behavior

Comment: I would assume this is the correct behaviour also. Apple probably sets an action for all the menu items in the popover which calls a method in the `NSPopUpButton` class which then calls the action you have linked to the popup button. By setting the action for the menu item directly it prevents this from taking place.